# How to ensure a password entered on command line is not stored at all on Linux server?

Tags: linux, security, logging, opensuse, sles

I've got a web page PHP script which runs p7zip on the server:

This passes a user supplied password for encrypting their uploaded files.

Secondly the password is then emailed via PHP to the recipient.

What are the possible locations the password could be stored?

I did a grep -r "Passw0rd" /var/log/*  nothing found.

Nothing in bash history either.

Dist is opensuse.

Many thanks!

Comment: are in your php script tempfiles involved? Possibly the password is shown in the process table for a short time.

Comment: I don't think so.  I suppose I could grep everything from root?  I'll have to build a test VM for this or try out of hours.

Comment: Under NO CIRCUMSTANCES should you e-mail the password to anybody. Salt'em and hash'em, never ever mail them...

Answer (score 2):

As this is being passed on the command-line, it's going to be *ephemerally* stored in the `/proc/` filesystem. Anyone who has a local account can get a list of the running processes and their command-line arguments.

```
 cat /proc/[pid]/cmdline
```

Which gives you a string. An example:

```
 /usr/bin/Xorg:0-backgroundnone-logverbose7-auth/var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-yrx0zQ/database-nolistentcpvt7
```

Which translates to:

```
 /usr/bin/Xorg:0 -background none -logverbose 7 -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-yrx0zQ/database -nolistentcp vt7
```

The `cmdline` pseudofile is world-readable, though it is only present when the process is actually running. These are visible in `top` after pressing the `c` key.

Some programs do manipulate that string so it isn't representative of what's actually running, though I don't know if php is one that allows such things.